# How to call JS function when autocomplete is updated

Tags: javascript, ajax, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm using primefaces `p:autocomplete` and need to modify the table of suggestions on clientside (insert a row if there are exactly X suggestions).

To do so, I'd like to call a JS function like:

```
function insertRow(){
    $('.autoCompletePanel tr:nth-child(X)').append('<tr><td>my tr</td></tr>');
}
```

Since the table of suggestions changes when typing, I need to call the function after every ajax request, *after* the autocomplete panel is (re-)rendered. How can I achive this? I could not find any `oncomplete` event which refers to the ajax request for retrieving the suggestions.

Comment: Does it work if you call the method from `completeMethod` in a bean? Like this `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("insertRow()");`

Comment: thanks, that works! Although it's more a workaround here ;-)

Comment: Yes, I agree. At least you have some solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `p:ajax` with `query` event, basically the `query` event is the same exact request of the actual query, in that way you can call the `oncomplete`, making sure that the query has executed completely:

```
 <p:ajax event="query" oncomplete="insertRow()" />
```